# How to check if a point(lonc,latc) lie on a great circle running from (lona,lata) to (lonb,latb)

Tags: latitude-longitude, great-circle

I'm trying to produce a boolean method that will return true if a point (lonc,latc) lies on a great circle arc starting at (lona,lata) and ending at (lonb,latb)

the point of the method returning true is so if you are in a location where you should be able to see this great circel the section you can see will be shown.

the jist is that you are at (lond,latd) with a small circle at 10degrees radius and I want to work out if the great circle and small circle will intersect. There will be multiple great circles but only one small circle.

I feel the simplest approach is to check any of the longitude and latitudes on the circumference of the small circle lie on a great circle line

any help will be most appreciated

Comment: You will need to explain how this is a programming question, as otherwise, it is off-topic here.

Comment: Sounds like a great maths question, but not programming related.

Comment: are you working on a sphere, am i getting you right?

Comment: Yes this is on a sphere more precisely the earth assuming it to be a sphere. I have a great circle mapped between (lona,lata) and (lonb,latb) and I want to verify that point (lonc,latc)  sits on this line. In another words this means i check if a line intersects this arc. they should therefore all be on the same plane. The programming relation to this question is that I want to get a algorithm which i can then use in an android application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have three latitude-longitude pairs (θ<sub>a</sub>, φ<sub>a</sub>), (θ<sub>b</sub>, φ<sub>b</sub>) and (θ<sub>c</sub>, φ<sub>c</sub>) and you want to determine whether point (θ<sub>c</sub>, φ<sub>c</sub>) lies on the great circle determined by (θ<sub>a</sub>, φ<sub>a</sub>) and (θ<sub>b</sub>, φ<sub>b</sub>). You can accomplish this for example using the following calculations:

1. Convert all latitude-longitude pairs to (x, y, z) triples using the following [formulae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Cartesian_coordinates): x = sin(θ)*cos(φ), y = sin(θ)*sin(φ), z = cos(θ). This will give you three triples (x<sub>a</sub>, y<sub>a</sub>, z<sub>a</sub>), (x<sub>b</sub>, y<sub>b</sub>, z<sub>b</sub>), (x<sub>c</sub>, y<sub>c</sub>, z<sub>c</sub>).
2. Determine the formula in cartesian coordinates of the plane going through points (x<sub>a</sub>, y<sub>a</sub>, z<sub>a</sub>), (x<sub>b</sub>, y<sub>b</sub>, z<sub>b</sub>) and the origin (0, 0, 0). The formula is x+b*y+c*z=0 and we seek *b* and *c* which can be determined from two simultaneous equations obtained by substituting coordinates of points A and B for x, y and z in the plane formula x+b*y+c*z=0.
3. Calculate the distance between point (x<sub>c</sub>, y<sub>c</sub>, z<sub>c</sub>) and the plane determined in point 2 using the following [formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28geometry%29#Distance_from_a_point_to_a_plane): d=abs(x<sub>c</sub>+b*y<sub>c</sub>+c*z<sub>c</sub>)/sqrt(1+b*b+c*c).
4. From the distance in cartesian coordinates you can find the angular distance between the point (x<sub>c</sub>, y<sub>c</sub>, z<sub>c</sub>) and the great circle determined by (θ<sub>a</sub>, φ<sub>a</sub>) and (θ<sub>b</sub>, φ<sub>b</sub>) using the following formula: α = asin(d).
5. Since you should not compare floating point numbers exactly you should have an angular threshold which determines how far a point can be from the great circle for you to still consider the point to lie on the circle. You then compare α determined in point 4 with the threshold to come up with the boolean value you seek.

Comment: point 3 will return the distance between c and b but what about a and c? as i assume we will then need to add these two values and compare to the total distance between a and b?

Comment: point 3 will return the distance between point C and **plane** determined by three points: A, B and the origin (sphere's center).

Answer (score 0):

assuming you're working on a sphere wich has points a and b marking a cirlce arc. and the you have point c on this sphree and you want to check if c is on the circlearc between a and b...

for this you can check the following:

1. generate a plane wich is formed from the vectors center-to-a and center-to-b
2. check if point c intersects with this plane (assuming the point is actually on the sphere, and not above or below it's surface)